# How to find all the sub strings that add up to a certain sum in python?

Tags: list, python-3.x, loops

Suppose I have a number 3523014 as a string. How can i find all the set of sub strings combined in form of a list, that add up to a certain digit say 10. I have written a code but i gives me a output of only few sub strings which are searched linearly.

Please fix the code -

```
def find_ten_substring(num_str):
        str1=""
        list1=[]
        a=0
        for i in range(0,len(num_str)):
                a=a+int(num_str[i])
                str1+=str(num_str[i])
                if(a==10):
                        a=0
                        list1.append(str1)
                        str1=""
        return(list1)


num_str="3523014"
print("The number is:",num_str)
result_list=find_ten_substring(num_str)
print(result_list)
```

The result comes as ['352']. 
The expected output should be ['5230', '23014', '523', '352']

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem ....

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
    s = sum(partial)

    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if s == target: 
        print "sum(%s)=%s" % (partial, target)
    if s >= target:
        return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i+1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n]) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_str="3523014"
    print("The number is:",num_str)
    result_list=subset_sum(list(map(int,num_str)),10)
    print(result_list)
```

Comment: This Program generates duplicates sub strings which are having different sorting orders. For example -  [2,3,5] and [5,2,3].

Comment: but if to combined then and form a number then it will be different

Answer (score 1):

Let me start with what's wrong with your code..

- In For loop, after completing "3","5","2" as iterations, you have
  set your a as zero     and str as empty, however, the next iteration
  for "For" loop is "3" at index-3 instead of it being "5" at
  index-1.
- from index-3, if you add all the values viz.,
  3,0,1,4, one still does not get sum as 10. Hence, you have only "352"
  as substring. To fix this, you can use two for loops.

Now my solution..

```
def find_ten_substring(num_str):
    ten_substr=[]         #list to store all substring
    for i in range(len(num_str)):
        sum=0
        sub_str=""
        for j in range(i,len(num_str)):
            sum+=int(num_str[j])
            if sum<10:
                sub_str+=num_str[j]
            elif sum==10:
                sub_str+=num_str[j]
                ten_substr.append(sub_str)
#checks if my current index is not my last index as at avoid index out of bound
#error in next line
                if (j!=len(num_str)-1):  
#checks if value at next index is "0". If true, it does not make sum as zero and
#substring as empty, instead continues with same value in next iteration.         
                    if (num_str[j+1]=="0"):
                        continue;
                    else:
                        break;
    return ten_substr; 

num_str="28353002"
print("The number is:",num_str)
result_list=find_ten_substring(num_str)
print(result_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest method to do this, using two for loops, here I have considered the sum target as 10

```
def find_ten_substring(num_str):
num_str=str(num_str)
number = list(map(int,num_str))
lst=[]
for i in range(0,len(num_str)):
    sum_val=0
    substr=""
    for j in range(i,len(num_str)):
        substr+=num_str[j]
        sum_of_substr=list(map(int,substr))
        sum_val=sum(sum_of_substr)
        if(sum_val==10):
            lst.append(substr)
return lst

num_str="3523014"
print("The number is:",num_str)
result_list=find_ten_substring(num_str)
print(result_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_ten_substring(num_str):
    str1=""
    list1=[]
    a=0
    for i in range(len(num_str)):
        a=0
        str1=""
        for j in range(i,len(num_str)):
            a=a+int(num_str[j])
            str1+=str(num_str[j])
            if(a==10):
                list1.append(str1)

    return(list1)


num_str="3523014"
print("The number is:",num_str)
result_list=find_ten_substring(num_str)
print(result_list)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_ten_substring(num_str):
    m=[]
    l=[]
    for i in range(0,len(num_str)):
        for j in range(i,len(num_str)):
            m.append(num_str[i:j+1])       
    for k in set(m):
        s=0
        for b in range(0,len(k)):
            s=s+int(k[b])
            if(s==10 and b+1==len(k)):
                l.append(k)
    return l

num_str="3523014"
print("The number is:",num_str)
result_list=find_ten_substring(num_str)
print(result_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_ten_substring(num_str):
    m=[]
    l=[]
    for i in range(0,len(num_str)):
        for j in range(i,len(num_str)):
            m.append(num_str[i:j+1])       
    for k in set(m):
        s=0
        for b in range(0,len(k)):
            s=s+int(k[b])
            if(s==10 and b+1==len(k)):
                l.append(k)
    return l

num_str="2825302"
print("The number is:",num_str)
result_list=find_ten_substring(num_str)
print(result_list)
```